# Python: Convert string representative of a string array to a list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to convert a string representative of a string array containing double quotes, single quotes and commas in its array items in to a python list when that array is passed to an API endpoint over postman. (Im am using Python 3.6)

Ex:
value passed in postman

```
"data":["bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''","'gehh', uujf "hjjj"",",,,hhhhh,, ","1"]
```

- element 1 = "bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''"
- element 2 = "'gehh', uujf "hjjj""
- element 3 = ",,,hhhhh,, "
- element 4 = "1"

What I tried and failed:

```
post_values = request.data['data']
post_values = ast.literal_eval(post_values)
```

Gives this error:

> During handling of the above exception (invalid syntax (,
>   line 1)), another exception occurred:

How can I convert this in to a 4 element list with relevant string escapes?

Comment: Is this whole thing "data":["bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''","'gehh', uujf "hjjj"",",,,hhhhh,, ","1"] in the beginning a sting ?

Comment: @SebNik It's passed as form data in postman. "data" is the key and its value is ["bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''","'gehh', uujf "hjjj"",",,,hhhhh,, ","1"]

Comment: "data" is the key and its value is ["bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''","'gehh', uujf "hjjj"",",,,hhhhh,, ","1"]

Answer (score 1):

When you write :`"bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''"`, the string starts with the first double quote, and finish with the second double quote, the `attd` is out of the string.
To use quotes and double quotes, you must put a `\` before. Like this:

```
"bacsr \"attd\" and, fhhh\'\'\'"
```

Without the `\`, Python understand that your string ended and don't know what is the `attd`.

PS. Sorry my English, I'm not fluent.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is clear enough.

```py
import re

data = """\
"data":["bacsr "attd" and, fhhh'''","'gehh', uujf "hjjj"",",,,hhhhh,, ","1"]\
"""

data = data.replace('[','').replace(']','')

# regular expression to split out quoted or unquoted tokens in data string into individual groups
pat = re.compile(r'(?:")?([^"]*)(?:(?(1)"|))')
groups = [* filter(None, pat.split(data))]

l = ['']
for token in groups[2:]:
     if token == ',':
         l.append('')
     else:
         l[-1] += token

post_values = {groups[0] : l} # construct the result dict

print(post_values)

print()
for v in post_values['data']:
    print(v)
```

output:

```py
{'data': ["bacsr attd and, fhhh'''", "'gehh', uujf hjjj", ',,,hhhhh,, ', '1']}

bacsr attd and, fhhh'''
'gehh', uujf hjjj
,,,hhhhh,,
1
```

note: element 2 is not same as what you give, but I can't achieve that.